# dataframe group by column and cut it by ranges pandas python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I'm trying to generate this query:

"**In which regions is present a bigger percent of infected old people(from 55), in which of young people(till 30) and in which adult people(31;54)**"

Let's clarify any question, first one means --> get the regions where the number of people older than 55 is the biggest percent than the other ages, so it should give me a list of the regions.
Analogically, the other two questions are the same but in different age ranges

My dataframe looks like this:

```
       Unnamed: 0  state sex   diag  death status T.categ  age
0              1    NSW   M  10905  11081      D      hs   35
1              2    NSW   M  11029  11096      D      hs   53
2              3    NSW   M   9551   9983      D      hs   42
3              4    NSW   M   9577   9654      D    haem   44
4              5    NSW   M  10015  10290      D      hs   39
          ...    ...  ..    ...    ...    ...     ...  ...
2838        2839  Other   M  11475  11504      A     het   46
2839        2840  Other   F  11420  11504      A     het   34
2840        2841  Other   M  11496  11504      A    haem   49
2841        2842  Other   M  11460  11504      A      hs   55
2842        2843  Other   M  11448  11504      A      hs   37
[2843 rows x 8 columns]
```

and my approach to the solution is to generate a dataframe that looks like this:

```
      (0, 30]       (30, 54]     (54, 200]
NSW     45                          ...
VCI     234            ... 
...                    535
Other                               56
```

With this, It would be easier to compare which state has the biggest amount by range.

**So far my code** can calculate the amount by ranges, but I don't know how to do it, including a group by of the regions...
Here is my code and result:

```py
data.groupby(pd.cut(data['age'], bins=[0, 30, 54, 200])).size()

[*] 
(0, 30]       736
(30, 54]     1937
(54, 200]     166
```

**Please feel free to recommend any other approach** or help me out with this query please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can groupby `state` as well:

```
data.groupby(['state', pd.cut(data['age'], bins=[0, 30, 54, 200])]).size()
```

The sample you included of your dataframe returned:

```
state               0  age      
NSW         (0, 30]      0
            (30, 54]     5
            (54, 200]    0
Other       (0, 30]      0
            (30, 54]     4
            (54, 200]    1
```